# List reverse-printing

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

Each node of a list holds, with the data, the address of the *successive* node. That's why recursion works well, like in the following example: it takes an input, such as `123456`, and then print it as a list `6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> NULL.`

```
/* Structure types ----------------------------------------------*/

typedef int data;
struct list_element {
   int                     data;
   struct list_element     *next;
};
typedef struct list_element ELEM;
typedef ELEM *LINK;


/* Recursive list create and list print---------------*/

LINK create_list(int n) {
   if (n == 0) {
      return NULL;
   }
   else {
      LINK head = (LINK) malloc(sizeof(ELEM));
      head -> data = n % 10;
      head -> next = create_list(n / 10);
      return head;
   }
}

void print_list(LINK head) {
   if(head == NULL)
      printf("NULL\n");
   else {
      printf("%d -> ", head -> data);
      print_list(head -> next);
   }
}

/* MAIN ---------------------------------------------------------*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int n; LINK ls;
   printf("\nType an integer:\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   ls = create_list(n);
   print_list(ls);
   return 0;
}
```

Nodes do not hold the address of their *previous* neighbor. From this consideration the question:

how can be possible to print a list from its *last* node, in order to have `NULL -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1` ?

The answers to the question [Reversing a linkedlist recursively in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080758/reversing-a-linkedlist-recursively-in-c) actually point to a slightly different problem. They aim to reverse the list itself. I do not aim to change the order of the data inside the list.

Comment: like `print_list(head -> next); printf(" -> %d", head -> data);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reversing a linkedlist recursively in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080758/reversing-a-linkedlist-recursively-in-c)

Comment: Note: for small jobs, recursion is fine, but you will generally want to stick to procedural solutions when the number of recursions may be large. Why? Because each recursion is a separate function call that reserves memory for distinct and separate stack frame to handle all variables local to that function. If you recurse 100,000 times, that's 100,000 separate function calls. That can really add up as the number of recursions continue to grow.

Comment: Why not use iterative on this problem ? If you search only recursive the good and only method is to reverse the list (create a new one if you want) and to print it. There are no magical solution that make it tail recursive without reverse the list.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do this by changing the order of the print calls. If you print the rest of the list first, then the order will be inverted.

```
print_list(head -> next);
printf("%d -> ", head -> data);
```

It's really a question of how you go through the list.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to interchange the printf statement and recursive call.

```
void print_list(LINK head){ 
     if(head == NULL)
          printf("NULL\n"); 
     else{
          print_list(head -> next);
          printf("%d -> ", head -> data);
      }
 }
```

Then the printf statement in the last recursive call will be executed first followed by others.

Answer (score 2):

When your list gets very large, recursion won't help as you will eventually run our of stack space.

If it is a *requirement* that you can print the list in reverse, you will have to adapt your data structure (and algorithms) to realize the requirement *without the posibility of running out of stack space*.

In short, you have to implement a doubly linked list, that is, not only have  `next` member but also a `prev` member.

Comment: Not necessarily - one *could* revert the list first and then on reverting it back, print out every element - all without recursion... Note: I don't say it's better, I just say: one does not *"have to"*...

Comment: @Aconcagua, Indeed. My requirement wasn't specific enough and should include "without modifying the list [because other tasks may be operating on it]".

Answer (score 1):

Just traverse to the last node while pushing printf statements onto the stack. Once you get to the end of the list, the stack will start to unwind and your print functions will get called.

```
void print_list_reverse(LINK head){                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    if(head == NULL)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            printf("NULL -> ");                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    else{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            print_list_reverse(head -> next);                                                                                                                                                                                               
            printf("%d -> ", head -> data);                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

}
```